# Conditional Execution of a Command based on used Documentclass

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, conditionals, document-classes

I use KOMA-Script-classes almost exclusively and because i don't like, that it always prints several elements of the table of contents in bold letters, i have included

```
\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\mdseries}.
```

Now, the problem is, that whenever i switch from writing a `scrreprt` to writing a `scrartcl`, i have to adjust the given line to

```
\addtokomafont{sectionentry}{\mdseries},
```

which is really annoying when your "in the flow" of writing.

Is there some kind of construct, that i can use to conditionally execute one of the above commands, based on which KOMA-Script-class i use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\ifx\chapter\undefined
  \addtokomafont{sectionentry}{\mdseries}
\else
  \addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\mdseries}
\fi
```

Comment: Wow, that was quick! And it's actually exactly what i want, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

By default font elements `chapterentry` (with `scrbook`or `scrreprt`) and `sectionentry` (with `scrartcl`) are only set to `\usekomafont{disposition}`.

So you can use

```
\BeforeStartingTOC{\addtokomafont{disposition}{\mdseries}}
```

Note, that this line would change the font of part entries, too und it would affect all lists under control of package `tocbasic`. If this should be restricted to the table of contents use the optional argument:

```
\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\addtokomafont{disposition}{\mdseries}}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\BeforeStartingTOC{\addtokomafont{disposition}{\mdseries}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Or with `scrreprt`:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

KOMA-Script from version 3.15 provides a command `\IfExistskomafont` to execute code depending on whether or not a font element does exist. So you can use it in this particular case:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}[2015/01/14]% at least KOMA-Script v3.15 needed
%\documentclass{scrartcl}[2015/01/14]% at least KOMA-Script v3.15 needed
\IfExistskomafont{chapterentry}{%
  \addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\mdseries}%
}{%
  \addtokomafont{sectionentry}{\mdseries}%
}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

BTW: If you also do not want to set the entries sans-serif, you can use:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}[2015/01/14]% at least KOMA-Script v3.15 needed
%\documentclass{scrartcl}[2015/01/14]% at least KOMA-Script v3.15 needed
\IfExistskomafont{chapterentry}{%
  \setkomafont{chapterentry}{}%
}{%
  \setkomafont{sectionentry}{}%
}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record, a solution that makes the code more explicit (using the KOMA script conditional \Ifstr):

```latex
\Ifstr{\KOMAClassName}{scrbook}{
  the class is scrbook
}{
  the class isn't scrbook
}
```

If the code needs to be compatible with non-KOMA classes:

```latex
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{
  % if non-KOMA class
}{% if KOMA class
  \Ifstr{\KOMAClassName}{scrbook}{the class is scrbook}{the class isn't scrbook}
}
\makeatother
```